# How do I clean inputs after clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have this code to clone some input fileds:

```
var cloneId = 1;
$("#more-address").click(function()
{
    var clone = $("#delivery-address-container").clone(true);
    clone.find(".deliveryMethod").prop("name", "deliveryMethod" + "[" + cloneId + "]");
    cloneId++;
    clone.appendTo("#delivery-address-container");
});
```

If if write something in the fileds and then press press the button with id `#more-address` I also get all the text in the input filed in my clone. How can I clean the input fileds in the clone?

I have tested to put `val("");`in my code but get the same result and no error like this

```
var cloneId = 1;
$("#more-address").click(function()
{
    var clone = $("#delivery-address-container").clone(true);
    clone.find(".deliveryMethod").prop("name", "deliveryMethod" + "[" + cloneId + "]").val("");
    cloneId++;
    clone.appendTo("#delivery-address-container").val("");
});
```

I have also tested to use this after `cloneId++;`

```
cloneId++;
clone.val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val('')` will only set the value of *one* input in the collection, and will only do so if the jQuery collection is that of inputs. If the collection is of a *container* (like the `#delivery-address-container`), using `.val` won't do anything.

You need to select the inputs which are descendants of the clone, not just call `.val` on the clone container.

```
clone.find('input').val('');
```

You're also creating duplicate IDs in the HTML (with the `#delivery-address-container`), which is invalid markup - consider removing the ID.